# Remove trailing whitespace via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to eliminate the whitespace following a "$", which is actually part of a string (ex. $ 100.00), and is dynamically generated per user-input.

My knowledge of regular expressions is very limited. So I'm not sure if this is something I should be using. Or perhaps a more practical solution would be .trim(). But as I understand it, that method looks for beginning and ending whitespace.

Here's the markup I'm working with:

```
<div class="sideBy_side">
   Estimated Total Price ‡<br>
   <span class="currency"><strong>$ 172.84</strong> <a class="popup currency"
   href="/" title="USD">USD</a></span>
</div>
```

And my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkmills1/8Zbcu/1/).

I'm still VERY new to jQuery and JS development in general. Any direction you can provide is appreciated.

Comment: I would, if possible, recommend that you try to fix the problem in the data source rather than dealing with the issue in the UI

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8Zbcu/6/ should do it.

Comment: A good way of handling this would be to have a value for displaying the currency and a hidden value containing just the number for further submiting and computations.
If the only problem is display you can just remove "$ " but be aware that positioning of the currency depends on culture.

Comment: Thanks everyone!!! While each of these solutions worked, the winning snippet was provided by @NiettheDarkAbsol!

jQuery('.currency strong').wrapInner('<span id ="dollarSymb"></span>').text(function (_, old) {
    return old.replace(/\s/g, '');
});

Those of you who take the time to help others learn are truly appreciated.

Thanks again!

Comment: @user3582095 Guess I'd better [post as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679661/remove-trailing-whitespace-via-jquery/24682212#24682212) then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this should do it:

```
.text(function(_,old) {return old.replace(/\s/g,'');})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Zbcu/6/)

Answer (score 2):

You can add this code:

```
jQuery('.currency').find('strong').text(function(_,txt){
   return txt.replace(" ","");// or txt.replace(/\$\s/,'$');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in vanilla JS:

`function stripWhitespaceAfterDollar(strInput){
    var pattern = /\$( )+/;
    return strInput.replace(pattern,"$");
}`

You want to look at `pattern`.

This is the regex here. To create a regex you put it within `//`.

We look for a dollar sign which is this part `\$`.
We need to escape the dollar because it is a regex operator.
Then we look for trailing whitepsace with `( )+`.
(We don't need the parentheses but I put them there for clarity). We could use `+`
The `+` regex operator means one or more, so we look for one or more spaces.

Then we use the string builtin replace, which looks for a string or regex and replaces it.
In this case we are looking for a dollar and then whitespace, and replacing it with just the dollar sign.

Comment: You could also use (as mentioned in other answers) the whitespace operator \s instead of the space

Answer (score 0):

If the whitespace is always the second character, you don't need a regular expression. Something like this will do the trick:

```
//wrap total price in span tag
jQuery('.currency strong').wrapInner('<span id ="dollarSymb"></span>');

var price = $("#dollarSymb").html();
var cut = price.substring(0, 1) + price.substring(2);
$("#dollarSymb").html(cut);
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8Zbcu/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex with:

```
var $element = $('.currency strong');
var text = $element.text();
var newText = text.replace(/(\$)\s*/g, '$1');

$element.text(newText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
jQuery(function(​$) {
    var pane = $('#inputPane');
    pane.val($.trim(pane.val()).replace(/\s*[\r\n]+\s*/g, '\n')
                               .replace(/(<[^\/][^>]*>)\s*/g, '$1')
                               .replace(/\s*(<\/[^>]+>)/g, '$1'));
});
```

Which gives the result:

```
<p>some text here...</p>
<p>more text here...</p>
```